# How making the listview onItemClick, Item Based instead of Position Based, specially after filter?

Tags: listview, search, android-intent, filter, onitemclick

I have a listView with 12 rows. Each of the rows after clicking goes to a new activity, not 12 activity but 1 activity called Content.java (change content by coding). But after applying search filter, for example if I have A, B and C in the list, when I enter B in editText I actually get the B as the remained row, but after click it goes to A activity.
The question is: How I make my OnItemClickListener intent Item Based instead of Position Based?
Here is my code:

```
Subjects_total_number = global.Subjects_total_number;
            Subjects = new String[Subjects_total_number];
            for(int x = 1; x < Subjects_total_number+1; x = x+1) {
                    String this_subject = "subject_" + String.valueOf(x);
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(this_subject, "string", getPackageName());
                    Subjects[x-1] = getResources().getString(resID);
    }

            setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textView1,
                            Subjects));    

               // set the OnItemClickListener

            lv = getListView();
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
            int position, long id) {                       
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Show_Subjects.class);
                    String Subject_number = String.valueOf(position+1);
                    i.putExtra("subject_number", Subject_number);
                    startActivity(i);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_to_right_forw, R.anim.slide_right_to_left_forw);
        }

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enter B in the edittext, your listview data doesn't change but just the view(the thing that you are seeing) changes. If you want your listview to have the data post filter, call notifydatasetChanged on your listview adapter(MyAdapter). Essentially what happens when you enter a text in the edittext is the listview shows the filtered option but the listview remains intact.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. But Can I ask you to change my code according to your comment to see the example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need to see your code as to where you are filtering based on your input. Only then I can help you with the way I have mentioned